# Specific algorithms for SSL implementation using c++

Tags: c++, openssl

I have SSL implementation which add all algorithms using OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms().

How can I specify limited algorithms such as:

```
# define SSL_TXT_ECDSA           "ECDSA"
# define SSL_TXT_AES_GCM         "AESGCM"
# define SSL_TXT_SHA256          "SHA256"
# define SSL_TXT_SHA384          "SHA384"
```

what is the right function and implementation to be used?

Comment: "Right" for what purpose?  Presumably all them are appropriate to use in certain situations, otherwise they wouldn't be supported by OpenSSL.

Comment: The idea that I want to enable specific algorithms, I did more search and found that I can use the following:  
 //OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); 
 char *cipher_list;
 cipher_list = "kECDHe:kECDH:kEECDH";
 SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ssl_Socket.sslContext, cipher_list);